# How do i set the width and height of the image in chrome app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://supersweetdomainbutnotcspfriendly.com/image.png',true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
document.body.appendChild(img);
};

xhr.send();
```

By using this i can get the image but with default size. so please tell me how do i set the width and height of that image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add two lines below `var img = document.createElement('img');`

```
img.setAttribute('width', '100');
img.setAttribute('height', '100');
```